# Programmatic MSIL injection

Tags: .net, cil

Let's say I have a buggy application like this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2 + 1 = {0}", Add(2, 1));
        }

        static int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + x; // <-- oops!
        }
    }
}
```

The application is already compiled and deployed into the wild. Someone has found the bug, and now they are requesting a fix for it. While I could re-deploy this application with the fix, its an extreme hassle for reasons outside of my control -- I just want to write a patch for the bug instead.

Specifically, I want to insert my own MSIL into the offending assmembly source file. I've never done anything like this before, and googling hasn't turned up any useful information. If I could just see a sample of how to do this on the code above, it would help me out tremendously :)

**How do I programmatically inject my own MSIL into a compiled .NET assembly?**

[Edit to add:] To those who asked: I don't need runtime hotswapping. Its perfectly fine for me to have the app closed, manipulate the assembly, then restart the program again.

[Edit one more time:] It looks like the general consensus is "manipulating the assembly is a **bad** way to patch a program". I won't go down that road if its a [bad idea](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx).

I'll leave the question open because MSIL injection might still be useful for other purposes :)

Comment: Do you want to do this while the application is running or when its offline?

Comment: In case you're wondering why I wouldn't just re-deploy my app, the software I'm writing consists of half a gig of exes and dlls, and its only released once or twice a year. Deploying the app is a big process. Patches and hotfixes will allow us to neutralize bugs between deployments more frequently.

Comment: Half a gig? Wow, that's a lot!

Comment: Removed your pseudo [.NET] tag for the second time.  We don't need fake tags in the title, I think we can gather it is .NET from both the words MSIL and the .net tag right below the title.

Comment: @Simucal: looks like we were editing the post at the same time, and one of my edits overwrote one of yours, which caused the pseudo-tag to be inserted after you removed it.

Comment: Here is blog post that shows a number of ways this type of injection/fix could be done: [Dynamically patching ASP.NET code in real-time? (Why don't WAF vendors do it?)](http://diniscruz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/dynamically-patching-aspnet-code-in.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the question I would ask is "how would you deploy the patch"?  Somewhere, you have to deploy something to fix a bug that is already out in the wild.  Why would recompiling the dll and releasing the fixed version really be an issue?  My guess is that figuring out how to programatically inject MSIL is going to be more trouble than simply redeploying a fixed assembly.

Comment: This is how we do things now, and its a huge PITA. Some clients are using the old versions of the program, some of the DLLs are signed, some are very large, and all of them are version-tied to one another. I run into a lot of brickwalls, more than I can explain in this comment, by swapping out DLLs.

Comment: If swapping DLLs is hard, how do you expect to inject code into them?

Comment: I still don't understand why fixing the bug in the source code and recompiling only this assembly would be a problem? It goes without saying that you should not break interfaces and leave the version number unincremented.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than injecting MSIL at runtime, have you considered inserting the source directly into the assembly?

You can disassemble with ildasm, insert your MSIL, and then reassemble with ilasm, then deploy the product of that.

Comment: This is the kind of solutions that people love to maintain.

Comment: And injecting MSIL into a running process is somehow easier?

Comment: +1: how much maintenance is really necessary for one-time patches?

Comment: You should never inject MSIL. Just rebuild and redeploy the new assembly. All this patching/disassembly is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Perhaps, but that's not what the question was about.

Answer (score 3):

If the reason you don't want to redeploy the whole stuff is because it is really half a gig, you should probably use some sort of binary patch tool - that's the first result on Google:

[Binary Diff http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/)

Answer (score 2):

good source of information...

[IL Programming ebook](http://www.vijaymukhi.com/documents/books/ilbook/contents.htm)

another is MS Press book on IL programming.

steps to decompile to IL and recompile

1.
ildasm /output=ConsoleApplication1.il ConsoleApplication1.exe

2.
//modify ConsoleApplication1.il code

3.
ilasm ConsoleApplication1.il

Answer (score 1):

If your exe is signed then that wouldn't be possible. Why can't you just release that single assembly, instead of shipping the whole application again? It seems like you're aiming for a complex solution for a simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use static MSIL Injection. Mono Cecil or PostSharp maybe helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You will need unmanaged code to perform this successfully but it can be done...

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time