# How to prevent MSIL runtime injection?

Tags: c#, security, cil

As seen here [Programmatic MSIL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512690/programmatic-msil-injection#) or here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time you can modify IL code at runtime using some tricky injections.

My question is : how to prevent that? For instance, if someone use that to bypass a security feature, how can i avoid that security hole?

Comment: This question is fundamentally flawed. If it's possible to bypass some security feature by modifying MSIL, it's also possible to bypass that same security feature without modifying MSIL. What security feature do you have in mind? Give details about that, and then answers can explain how bypassing that can be prevented completely, or, why bypassing that can never be prevented completely.

Comment: Interesting question, welcome to why there are businesses whose sole purpose is to prevent these types of measures. I don't have an answer, but I can say that about 15 years ago I used to have a lot of fun with SoftICE debugger cracking software for various nefarious purposes. The lesson I learned then is that "they (we) always find a way!". It's much more difficult these days but it quickly becomes a balance between annoying legitimate users and preventing badness.

Comment: Prevent what exactly? Ability of user to run any code on their machines or modify binaries any way they want? Running code on your own server is only option available unless you can afford building closed system similar to Xbox/PS

Comment: For instance for a login purpose. You log in into an app, the process is secured by ssl, hash verification, anti tampering, anti debugging, and so on.. but right now all the 'bad guy' has to do is log in into a normal account and then unlock app features through msil injection at runtime. And i wanna prevent that.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060508-22/?p=31283

Comment: I would recommend that such mission critical code should be written in native code (and use PInvoke or via C++.Net to interoperate) or using NGen to compile it native code, which makes it way harder to do it, but not impossible.

Comment: Still it would be possible to bypass anything, and the best way is to use your login function to return some token and all relevant information should be encrypted and need the token to decrypt, I hope you get the idea etc.

Answer (score 2):

> how to prevent that?

You can't, **as far as I understand**. But you can do make it not easy.

In the simple case, you don't even need to inject IL. You can do IL weaving to modify the assembly. For example, you can find the login method ant delete the original IL code and simply return `true`, or you can jump to your own login method.

```
public bool Login(string userName)
{
    // original method did security checks 
    // and return true if the user is authorized
    // your implementation can return true or jump to other method
}
```

For this you must to do it when the application is not running, you modifying the assembly itself. You can do it with `mono.cecil` and you can look on [StaticProxy.Fody](https://github.com/BrunoJuchli/StaticProxy.Fody) for example.

The other case is inject code to running assembly. and this is divide to two cases:

1. When the code isn't jitted\ngen'd
2. When the code is jitted\ngen'd

For the first case is more easy, You still have the IL of each method and you inject your own IL instructions.

The second case is more complex because the Jitter redirect the IL pointer to the machine code.

For two of them you can see a bunch of articles\libraris to make the inject work.

- [Codecope](http://getcodecop.com/)
- [Article 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time)
- [Article 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer)

But even if you however make it impossible to inject, you still not protected. Because you can modify the bytes itself. See [this article](http://www.sunshine2k.de/reversing/tuts/tut_ci_dotnet_msgbox/tut_ci_dotnet_msgbox.html) for details.

For all above method, there is cases when it more complex to do the work. For example, Generics, DynamicMethods, prevent load assemblies to your process (which is needed in some cases).

To summarize, you can do it very hardly to inject your code but not prevent it.

Comment: "You can do IL weaving to modify the assembly. For example, you can find the login method ant delete the original IL code and simply return true, or you can jump to your own login method." No, because my application is protected by an anti-tamper. So the only way right now to bypass my login system is by injecting MSIL at runtime. And it's possible, because i cracked my own program quite easily. what i'm searching for is HOW TO PROTECT my program from runtime injection, not how to the injection itself. Thanks for answering, though.

Comment: @JacquesMartin I understand what you search for. My answer is, that you can't AFAIK, and I explained why. I would be very happy if someone will answer how can you protect from injection.