# Is it possible to replace a C# method in another process at runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies, cil

I've seen that through reflection you can call and even replace internal and private methods of classes in other assemblies within your own process.

(I love LogMan's answer to this related question: [Dynamically replace the contents of a C# method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method))

I would like to dynamically replace (wrap) a method of a loaded .NET assembly in another (native) process in the system, specifically ehrecvr.exe.

Is this possible?  Alternatively, is it possible to add an extra assembly to load when that binary is run, which would then be in-process for the method replacement?

Comment: Check if this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38204281/986184) help. If you need some other info please be more specific (maybe with example) and I'll try to help.

Comment: RhInjectLibrary mentioned in the codeproject link in that question sounds like it might be what I am looking for, thanks.