# What is a better way to modify IL code of the method?

Tags: c#, code-generation, reflection.emit

I need to replace `call` instruction in the method `A()` from `this.B()` to `this.C()`. Now I use [this helper](https://gist.github.com/jbevain/104001) to get IL instructions of Method `A()` then replace `call` instruction and then use IL generator to emit all instructions manually.
Note: There is a nuget with that helper - [Mono.Reflection](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Reflection)

Part of the code to demonstrate what I need:

```
var emitter = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
foreach (var cmd in baseMethodInfo.GetInstructions())
{
    if (cmd.Operand == null)
        emitter.Emit(cmd.OpCode);
    else
    {
        switch (cmd.OpCode.OperandType)
        {
            case OperandType.InlineMethod:
            {
                var currentMethodInfo = cmd.Operand as MethodInfo;
                //check that it's this.B() and get this.C() then
                var methodToReplace = installedMethods.SingleOrDefault(m => m.MethodInfo == currentMethodInfo);
                if (methodToReplace != null)
                    emitter.EmitCall(cmd.OpCode, methodToReplace.MethodBuilder, null);
                else
                    emitter.EmitCall(cmd.OpCode, currentMethodInfo, null);
                break;
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But I guess somebody already implement something like that and I want to use it because most likely it's a more better and safety way. I know Mono.Cecil gives ability to replace instruction but as I know it's only for `asembly loading time` but I need `runtime`.

Comment: Why exactly do you need "runtime"? It looks like you're creating a new method anyway, couldn't you use Cecil create a new assembly containing just the method you need?

Comment: Unfortunately I get info about which methods should be replaced in the runtime. `this.B()` and `this.C()` just for example.

Comment: Why is that an issue? You can create and then load an assembly at runtime.

Comment: Possible perfomance issue. In each place where I replace the code I will need to generate (the same in different approaches), save and load assembly. With reflection.emit I can declare a single assembly. But I didn't think about the suggested way. I can try it and test perfomance. Thank you.

Comment: Assembly loading time **is** runtime.  If you try to do it after the assembly is loaded then you are very likely to be too late, it has to be done before the just-in-time compiler generates the machine code from the IL.

Comment: I'm generating another assembly with method `A()` so it's not an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with Cecil is the easiest way. And as svick wrote, you can do it even if the info of which method you need to replace is coming in runtime (of-course just if this method meet your performance requirements).

**But** if you want to check other options, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38204281/986184).